# Add floating button inside v-img in v-card

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I would like to have a floating at the bottom right side of the image inside a card.

here's my sample https://codepen.io/chunallen/pen/bPGJOP?editors=1000

The problem here is the button is behind of the `v-card-title`

**Expected Result**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `style="height: 100px; position: relative"` to `v-card-title`, move the btn beneath the h3, and change bottom to top then it'll work.

```
<v-card-title primary-title style="height: 100px; position: relative">
    <div>
        <h3 class="headline mb-0">Kangaroo Valley Safari</h3>
        <v-btn color="pink" dark small absolute top right fab>
            <v-icon>add</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </div>
</v-card-title>
```

[Sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKYwYR?editors=1000)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but for people with the same issue:

- a button placed inside v-img will cut the button of.
- a seperate card around the image and the button in the card (after the image) does the trick

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30033229)